# C# inject custom code into the compiler to create custom compiler warnings and errors

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, dsl

Can I add code to the compiler to create custom compiler warnings and errors?

Maybe with Attributes?

I am looking towards an internal DSL.

So something like:

```
[MustAssign]
public string Val {get; set;}
```

Comment: Have you looked into `PostSharp`?

Comment: not a duplicate, new question

Comment: @ChrFin no did it just now but I can not see how to create a custom compiler warning.

Comment: Maybe also check the new .NET compiler platform (Roslyn)...

Comment: Yes Roslyn this seems to be it.